# Homework - Find seed number of random

Tags: java, encryption, generator

For homework I have to calculate a seed number. We are given an inputfile, which we have to decrypt into an outputfile. 
What I have to do, is to find the 'seed' number, to generate random number, so the 'encryption' is random.

The only hint we got is that the original source text is an English novel. We have to calculate 'seed' completely with a program. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

I thought, a for-loop that decrypts the file everytime, until the outputfile does not have a 'special' character? But I do not know how to do this.

I have the en/decryption function here:

```
  static char crypt(char input, int random, boolean encrypt)
  {
    assert random>=0&&random<=95 : "Random has to be between 0 and 95.";
    if(input=='\n')
      return '\n';
    if((int)input>=32||(int)input<=127)
    {
      if(encrypt)
      {
        char inputEncrypted=(char)((input-32+random+96)%96+32);
        return inputEncrypted;
      } else
      {
        char inputDecrypted=(char)((input-32-random+96)%96+32);
        return inputDecrypted;
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

My main function is:

```
package ..;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give true if you want to encrypt, false for decrypt: ");
    boolean encrypt=scanner.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println("Give the input filename");
    File inputFile=new File(scanner.next());
    InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

    System.out.println("Give the output filename");
    File outputFile=new File(scanner.next());
    OutputStreamWriter writer;
    try
    {
     writer=new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
      {
        Random generator=new Random(seed); //this one I have to calculate
        int c;
        while((c=reader.read())>=0)
        {
          writer.write(crypt((char)c,generator.nextInt(96),encrypt));
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.out.println("File is not found!");
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
```

A piece of the  268Kb .txt file, that we have to decrypt is:

> r(8Of%?.)d*Ya |V?qS&@m$!wJKzfpu\CdQbir*80dB* J)6znu/gFf%,C=u
>   u/:DP_,K@3'6])[eu=#y^+{WKK3k2N IOWwmW,H.0iF+!+J/'/-T 'DQQg0N
>   2o71cRZ67X
>   q!=dJ0s~ldq6}a{-Q C\H"{s@]ptRqU}A8y~gRHlf "@.H]bwXk|~e<}SBl5mqsNAa$SA-!3-Bf,^~#x/sQzpJC).6a;'$(pm.bsU^J~"(K@|<dFH5D!cY*>%NPIjr+KVw|3G0$Vx{%7Au#w\$<~Wk@K%]eIba}h3Yd
>   koT!7+Q&~YnP{vX$i29IeIE.d|?\rL6Uf0lc7wy;"Pe

Comment: With the approach you're using, you don't need an output file until the very end.  Just read in the input file into a string and test for special characters with every character that you read in.  Only write an output file if you read all characters from the input file, and none of them get shifted to a special character.

Comment: @Jordan yes that sounds logic, but how do I do this? First make a for-loop, then create a string, then read file into this string, and then if string does not contain @, 'seed' = i. Or how?

Comment: Make a for loop, create StringBuilder, read individual characters into the StringBuilder on at a time. Use a `continue` to jump to the next iteration of the loop if you see a character that encodes to a special character which will create a new String Builder (make sure to close your reader first).  If you reach the end of the loop, it means that there were no special characters, so get the string value of your StringBuilder, write it to a file, and break out of the for loop.

Comment: I have not worked with StringBuilder or Continue before, so I do not think I am allowed to use that. What I have now: `for(int i=1;i<=4711;i++)
      {
        Random generator=new Random(i);
        int d;
        while((d=reader.read())>=0)
        {
          String test=""; test=test+crypt((char)d,generator.nextInt(96),encrypt);
          if(!test.contains("@")){ //write into outputfile
            }`

Comment: @Jordan, can you maybe help me? Bit desperate now..

Comment: Someone that wants to help? The answer below I tried, but does not give the right output

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wrote at the end:

```
for(int i=1;i<=4711;i++) { 
    Random generator=new Random(i); 
    int d;
    while((d=reader.read())>=0) { 
        String test=""; 
        test=test+crypt((char)d,generator.nextInt(96),encrypt);
        if(!test.contains("@"))
        {
            //write into outputfile 
        }
    }
```

Pretty close.  You should instead break the while loop and carry on with the next key if it is a bad character (and clear `test`):

```
for(int i=1;i<=4711;i++) { 
    Random generator=new Random(i); 
    int d;
    String test="";
    boolean finished = true;
    while((d=reader.read())>=0) { 
        char c = crypt((char)d,generator.nextInt(96),encrypt);
        if (c == '@') {
            // Forget this key... move on - break the while loop
            finished = false;
            break;
        }
        // Append the decrypted char
        test=test+c;
    }
    if (finished) {
        write test into outputfile 
        // No need to try any more keys, so break the for loop.
        break;
    }
```

This is all assuming your test for invalid character `(c == '@')` is correct.

Comment: Thank you for helping! The code now gives an error: unknown source. In the `while((d=reader.read())>=0)`. How can I fix this? It says 'stream closed'

Comment: It still does not work. I fixed the error, but the output.txt is not right.

Comment: I tried your posted algorithm, and I could not get it to work with your sample data.  You wrote "A piece of the .txt file".  Is that from the start of the input text, or something from the middle?  Here is what I did:  I looped over all the input values, and printed the output for each decrypted string (in other words, I did not stop decrypting for bad chars, and I did not exit when I got a 'valid' string).  All the outputs were garbage.  I think there might be something wrong with your stated decryption algorithm.  Also, where did the number 4711 come from?